# vault.keystore values not visibles in java application

Tags: java, jboss, keystore

I want to use a password in my java app saved in the jboss vault.keystore. I add the value with `vault.sh` (or `vault.bat` in windows) and validating my key exists in the vault, and in my app I try to use it with:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
KeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(JBOSSPATH+"/vault.keystore"),null);
```

but in the `keyStore` variable, I only obtain 1 key: `vault` and I can't get other values.